# How to add google structure data in Blog Post?

Tags: google, html

I want to add Google structure data in WordPress Blog posts, pages. Where i need to place Structure data (in body or head section)? What is the correct schema structure for Posts or pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the Google Codelabs:

> Structured data provides a way to standardize information about a page
>   and classify the page content. JSON-LD is used for data in a simple
>   JavaScript-oriented object notation and is Google's preferred format
>   for structured data. JSON-LD should be inside a  element in
>   either the  or  of the page.

There are some examples of how to implement it as part of the Codelab guide [Add structured data to your web pages](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/structured-data/index.html).

As to what data you use, it depends what your website posts and pages are about. There are many different schemas depending on the content, you can browse them on the https://schema.org website, along with JSON-LD example code. For example, if your posts are [reviews](https://schema.org/Review) for a book:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "breadcrumb": "Books > Literature & Fiction > Classics",
  "mainEntity":{
          "@type": "Book",
          "author": "/author/jd_salinger.html",
          "bookFormat": "http://schema.org/Paperback",
          "datePublished": "1991-05-01",
          "image": "catcher-in-the-rye-book-cover.jpg",
          "inLanguage": "English",
          "isbn": "0316769487",
          "name": "The Catcher in the Rye",
          "numberOfPages": "224",
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
            "price": "6.99",
            "priceCurrency": "USD"
          },
          "publisher": "Little, Brown, and Company",
          "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingValue": "4",
            "reviewCount": "3077"
          },
          "review": [
            {
              "@type": "Review",
              "author": "John Doe",
              "datePublished": "2006-05-04",
              "name": "A masterpiece of literature",
              "reviewBody": "I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives and grow to adulthood.",
              "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": "5"
           }
            },
            {
              "@type": "Review",
              "author": "Bob Smith",
              "datePublished": "2006-06-15",
              "name": "A good read.",
              "reviewBody": "Catcher in the Rye is a fun book. It's a good book to read.",
              "reviewRating": "4"
            }
          ]
        }
}
</script>
```

You would probably want to [use a hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) to insert the script into the head of your site, pulling in data from your page/post.

Answer (score 0):

**All In One Schema Rich Snippets**

This plugin will help you 
[link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-schemaorg-rich-snippets/)

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin.